# A function that shuffles an array passed as an argument

Tags: c, arrays, random, shuffle

I'm working on a project at school and I want to create a function that shuffles an array passed as an argument. I tried to create one, but it didn't work as I expected...

In this code, I'm trying to copy the elements of the passed array and set them in random order in a second array. Then, copy them again in the passed array..

**This is the source code:**

```
void shufarray(int* array, int b)
{
    int hold[b];  
    int i,k;  
    int randV=0, randHold=0;
    srand(b);  
    for(i=0; i<b; ++i) {      
        hold[rand() % (b-1)] = array[i]; 
        k=0;
        do { 
            if(k==0) { 
                randHold = randV;
                k=-1;
            } //end if
            randV = rand()%(b-1);         
        } while(randHold != randV);//end of do\while stetment 
        hold[randV] = array[i];     
    } //end for  
    for(i=0;i<b;++i) {
        array[i]=hold[i]; 
    } //end for 
} //end shufarray()
```

**And this is the output:**

```
hold[ 0 ] = 8
hold[ 1 ] = 11
hold[ 2 ] = 2
hold[ 3 ] = 15
hold[ 4 ] = 18
hold[ 5 ] = 10
hold[ 6 ] = 11
hold[ 7 ] = 17
hold[ 8 ] = 24
hold[ 9 ] = 21
hold[ 10 ] = 12
hold[ 11 ] = 2
hold[ 12 ] = 15
hold[ 13 ] = 9
hold[ 14 ] = 13
hold[ 15 ] = 1
hold[ 16 ] = 15
hold[ 17 ] = 1
hold[ 18 ] = 22
hold[ 19 ] = 11
hold[ 20 ] = 11
hold[ 21 ] = 18
hold[ 22 ] = 17
hold[ 23 ] = 4
hold[ 24 ] = 7
shuffled_hold[ 0 ] = 7
shuffled_hold[ 1 ] = 32561
shuffled_hold[ 2 ] = 22
shuffled_hold[ 3 ] = 0
shuffled_hold[ 4 ] = 18
shuffled_hold[ 5 ] = 8
shuffled_hold[ 6 ] = -632114865
shuffled_hold[ 7 ] = 32561
shuffled_hold[ 8 ] = -628693440
shuffled_hold[ 9 ] = 11
shuffled_hold[ 10 ] = 15
shuffled_hold[ 11 ] = 18
shuffled_hold[ 12 ] = 1
shuffled_hold[ 13 ] = 13
shuffled_hold[ 14 ] = 15
shuffled_hold[ 15 ] = 12
shuffled_hold[ 16 ] = 17
shuffled_hold[ 17 ] = 0
shuffled_hold[ 18 ] = 4
shuffled_hold[ 19 ] = 17
shuffled_hold[ 20 ] = 7
shuffled_hold[ 21 ] = 0
shuffled_hold[ 22 ] = -1
shuffled_hold[ 23 ] = 0
shuffled_hold[ 24 ] = 0
```

So I'm trying to understand the principle of this operation, anyone helps me to find what is exactly the problem.. Thanks.

Comment: Your shuffling algorithm just doesn't make any sense. You're just randomly copying the elements of `array` to `hold`, sometimes you'll overwrite one you did already, other times you'll leave some elements of `hold` uninitialized. There's not an identifiable problem with your code - the logic just isn't there.

Comment: Your algorithm seems needlessly complicated (and broken). Search for [“random permutation”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation).

Comment: You can avoid the temporary array by implementing a [Fisher–Yates_shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm). It's fewer lines of code than what you have, and best of all, it works.

Comment: what is exactly logic that I have to follow?

Comment: FYI, using `srand(b)` will always give you the same permutation based on length.  You should use an actual entropy source like `time(NULL)` if you want randomization.

Comment: thanks for everyone, I'll try to figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**THE PROBLEM**

In the previous code, I thought that the solution is to create an array `hold[]`that holds randomly copied elements from `array[]`. than copy elements from `hold[]` back again to `array[]`.the problems are:

> - the `hold[]` is uninitialized
> - sometimes the program will overwrite an element overwrote already
> - srand(b) will always give the same permutation based on length

**THE SOLUTION**

> I modify the code at the light of the references that are suggested in comments.

the correct way to do it is to start from the last element `array[n-1]`, swap it with a randomly selected element from the whole array (including the last one). Now consider the array `from 0 to n-2` (size reduced by 1), and repeat the process till we hit the first element. Following is the detailed algorithm:

```
  for i from n - 1 downto 1 do
       j = random integer with 0 <= j <= i
       exchange a[j] and a[i] .
```

**THE CODE**

```
void shufarray(int* array, int b){
    int i,k=0;
    srand(time(NULL));//set the seed
    /* Starting from the last element and swap one by one.
     * NOTE: i > 0 it's because there's no need to run for the first element */
    for (i = b-1; i > 0; i--){
        int j = rand() % (i+1);
        //swap
        k =  array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = k;
    }//end for
}//end shufarray()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
hold[ 0 ] = 8
hold[ 1 ] = 11
hold[ 2 ] = 2
hold[ 3 ] = 15
hold[ 4 ] = 18
hold[ 5 ] = 10
hold[ 6 ] = 11
hold[ 7 ] = 17
hold[ 8 ] = 24
hold[ 9 ] = 21
hold[ 10 ] = 12
hold[ 11 ] = 2
hold[ 12 ] = 15
hold[ 13 ] = 9
hold[ 14 ] = 13
hold[ 15 ] = 1
hold[ 16 ] = 15
hold[ 17 ] = 1
hold[ 18 ] = 22
hold[ 19 ] = 11
hold[ 20 ] = 11
hold[ 21 ] = 18
hold[ 22 ] = 17
hold[ 23 ] = 4
hold[ 24 ] = 7
shuffled_hold[ 0 ] = 24
shuffled_hold[ 1 ] = 9
shuffled_hold[ 2 ] = 8
shuffled_hold[ 3 ] = 1
shuffled_hold[ 4 ] = 15
shuffled_hold[ 5 ] = 11
shuffled_hold[ 6 ] = 11
shuffled_hold[ 7 ] = 21
shuffled_hold[ 8 ] = 17
shuffled_hold[ 9 ] = 7
shuffled_hold[ 10 ] = 11
shuffled_hold[ 11 ] = 11
shuffled_hold[ 12 ] = 18
shuffled_hold[ 13 ] = 10
shuffled_hold[ 14 ] = 1
shuffled_hold[ 15 ] = 15
shuffled_hold[ 16 ] = 13
shuffled_hold[ 17 ] = 2
shuffled_hold[ 18 ] = 18
shuffled_hold[ 19 ] = 4
shuffled_hold[ 20 ] = 17
shuffled_hold[ 21 ] = 2
shuffled_hold[ 22 ] = 12
shuffled_hold[ 23 ] = 15
shuffled_hold[ 24 ] = 22
```

**REFERENCES:**
[Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm)

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));/` should not be called repeatedly in `shufarray()`.  Better to call only once in the life of the program - perhaps `main()`.